# VS2010 Build of .NET v3.5 projects fail due to a potential .NET v4.0 reference

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build, project-reference

Attempting to build a Visual Studio 2010 solution with 132 projects which do not use any file references (only project references). When I build the entire solution, I get many build errors like this:

```
The type or namespace name 'xxxx' does not exist in the namespace '<namespace name>' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

The target framework version for ALL projects in the solution is v3.5.

Hence I started building projects one by one based on the Project Build Order. And on one of the projects (say project A), I get the below info in the Build Output (note the framework version). This project A builds successfully.
When I build the next project, say project B, which references project A through a project reference (not file reference), then it throws the above build error. Hence it seems project B is the culprit.

```
 Compile complete -- 0 errors, 54 warnings
  <ProjectName> -> <filepath>\<filename>.dll
  Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.1
  Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

**Details of project B**

Solution configuration is Debug.

- In the References tree of project B, the properties of the project A reference shows

> 1) "Runtime Version" as v2.0.50727.
>   2) "Copy local" as True.
>   3) "Strong Name" as True.
>   4) "Version" as 1.0.xxxx.xx (as specified in the AssemblyInfo.cs of project A)
>   5) There is no "Specific Version" key (because it is a project reference)

- the AssemblyInfo.cs of project B has the following:

> 1) [assembly: ComVisible(false)]
>   2) [assembly:Guid("xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx")]
>   3) [assembly:AssemblyVersion("1.0.xxxx.xx")]
>   4) [assembly:AssemblyFileVersion("9.0.xxxx.xx")]

- the project B properties has the following:

> 1) "Target Framework" as ".NET Framework 3.5"
>   2) "Output Type" as "Class Library"
>   3) "Treat warnings as errors" as "None"

**My Question(s)**

Now, the target framework specified in the properties of ALL my projects is *.NET Framework 3.5*.

***How does the build engine use a GAC Utility of v4.0 when my target framework is v3.5?***

Searched all files to see if .NET 4.0 is configured somewhere but could not find it.
This seems to be potentially the root cause of the above issue. Or am I missing something else? I believe I have covered the usual suspects.

***Also why does the Runtime Version of project A reference in project B say v2.0.50727 when the target framework version for both projects is v3.5?***

PS:
I tried removing the project reference and adding its file reference instead, still gives the same build error. (This usually used to work before when it was a long name issue but its not in this case).

**UPDATE 1:**

The build output for the above build error is:

```
Compile complete -- 13 errors, 0 warnings
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1360,9): 
warning MSB3258: The primary reference "<project A reference name>" could not be resolved
because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly 
"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxx" 
which has a higher version "4.0.0.0" than the version "2.0.0.0" in the current target framework.
```

**UPDATE 2:**

The Post-build event command-line for project A has the following which explains why the build uses the GAC Utility of v4.0! Now I need to figure how to get the v3.5 Gacutil in there.
My second question still stands though.

```
cd "$(ProjectDir)"
cd ..\..\..\Bin
gacutil.exe /if "$(TargetPath)"
```

Comment: BTW, the AssemblyInfo is irrelevant.

Comment: True. I put that in to show that the AssemblyVersion used is the same and i am not referencing some other version of the assembly (accidentally).

Comment: Take this opportunity to get rid of all those post build events.  Using the GAC on your dev machine is a Bad Idea.

Comment: @HansPassant, Is there any reason why it is not a good practice to use GAC on a dev machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your second question:

.Net 3.0 and .Net 3.5 are simply new DLLs that run on the existing CLR 2.0.

There are no *runtime* versions between 2.0 and 4.0.

Comment: Gosh! you are right! That slipped out of my mind totally. Thanks